# Font groups of FIFA world cup brazil 2014

Tags: font-identification

Someone can help me to identify this font used in the groups of FIFA world cup brazil 2014

Thanks.
 [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it's [Gotham](http://www.typography.com/fonts/gotham/overview/), probably Bold:

[image: Gotham test drive screenshot]