# What font is in this scoreboard of the FIFA Club World Cup?

Tags: font-identification

I wanna know this font used by FIFA in some events.

[image: FIFA scoreboard]

I have also posted at [dafont](http://www.dafont.com/pt/forum/read/141302/fifa-scoreboard-font-somebody-know-this-font).

Comment: There was a similar question not long ago: [**Font groups of FIFA world cup brazil 2014**](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/25361/8708). However, the font in this question is not Gotham (the vertex of the M does not touch the baseline in Gotham).

Answer (score 5):

It's Frutiger, probably [Condensed Black](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/frutiger/cond-black/); it's not easy to tell the variant because of the low resolution of the scoreboard, but the digits and R are distinctive.

[image: Frutiger Condensed Black]

Answer (score 2):

It can be [**Proxima Nova Condensed**](https://typekit.com/fonts/proxima-nova-condensed) Bold or Extra Bold. Check yourself, too:

[image]

Comment: Very similar, but the `R` in the sample is curved (like in Frutiger) while the `R` in Proxima is straight.

Answer (score -1):

[WC fifa 2014](http://www.maillots-foot-actu.fr/coupe-du-monde-2014/pagode-bold-police-ecriture-fifa-2014/)

This is the 'Pagode' font, made originally for FIFA 2014